# App Crashing: Mutating method sent to immutable object

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I am trying to add an object to an `NSMutableArray`. Initially I assign some response data to the array, and can display it in a table view. After loading more data, it seems to be crashing when trying to add the new information to my original array.

I am using AFNetworking for this:

```
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    if(!_myArray){
        _myArray = [responseObject objectForKey:@"data"];
    }
    else{
        [_myArray addObject:[responseObject objectForKey:@"data"]];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

The error I am getting is as follows

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

Can anybody help out with this?

Answer (score 2):

The object you're retrieving from the `responseObject` dictionary is most likely not an `NSMutableArray`, but an (immutable) `NSArray`. You have to create a mutable copy to be able to change it:

```
//...
if (!_myArray) {
    _myArray = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"data"] mutableCopy];
}
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like AFNetworking generates immutable objects. You should call `-mutableCopy` instead of just assigning the result of `-objectForKey:` directly.

Also are you really intending to have a bunch of nested arrays? It seems like it would make more sense if you added the contents of the response array, rather than the array itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the copy of your array. After that you have to modify that array using, `[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: ]`

Answer (score -1):

Your array is must be mutable array

Use NSMutablearray instead NSArray